# AssertionError: Test node [test_rosjava/tester]

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good night,

I am testing ROSJava and I am using the guide from:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava

When I am executing the example:
rostest --text test/rosjava_test.launch

I receive the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rostest/src/rostest/runner.py",
> line 60, in fn
> self.fail(message) AssertionError: Test node [test_rosjava/tester] does
> not exist or is not executable

I would like to know what is the problem.

Cheers

Juan Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9814/assertionerror:-test-node-%5Btest_rosjava/tester%5D/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2011-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki page was sort of outdated. I've updated it accordingly. You can run the test as follows:

```
roscd test_rosjava
make test
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-17**:
NOTE for future readers: this is for the old, JNI-based rosjava